# Symfony multiple user types and custom user provider

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle, symfony4, fosoauthserverbundle

I am designing architecture and database for an application similar to Uber.  And I am stuck with designing `User` entity and creating custom User provider. There are 2 types of `User` `driver` and `customer`. User can register his emails as both `driver` and `customer`.

Is there good reading or projects where I can learn about best approach to creating app with multiple user types.

This is what I currently came up with:

I started with abstract `User` entity

```
/**
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="discr", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"customer" = "Customer", "driver" = "Driver"})
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UserRepository")
 */
abstract class User {
     /**
      * @ORM\Id()
      * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
      * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
      */
      protected $id;
}
```

and `Customer` class looks like:

```
class Customer extends User
{
  /**
   * @ORM\Id()
   * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
   * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
   */
  protected $id;

  /**
   * @var string
   *
   * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=false, name="email", unique=true)
   */
  protected $email;
```

`Driver` class:

```
 class Driver extends User
   {
  /**
   * @ORM\Id()
   * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
   * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
   */
  protected $id;

  /**
   * @var string
   *
   * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=false, name="email", unique=true)
   */
  protected $email;
```

However I am not sure if this User entities structure is a good idea. But if I continue with this db model what would be best strategy for user authorisation? 
I am planning to use FOS oAuth for security. Is it better to have separate firewalls for each type of `User`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should consider a roles based approach instead of basing your design on type

if you need polymorphic queries and relationships, the joined strategy is probably your best option

like that, a User can register his emails as both driver and customer.
User A has roles [DRIVER_ROLE, USER_ROLE]

Comment: To avoid misleadings/typos with new Symfony users it is better to correct in `ROLE_DRIVER`, `ROLE_CUSTOMER` your example, because In Symfony each role assigned to the User must begin with the `ROLE_` prefix.

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply. it's very helpful. I have followup question tho. What if user has `aboutMe` property that needs to be changed depending on which profile (driver or customer) he switched to?

Comment: Then you'd better separate the 2 kind of users. A little reading on handling this with the associated firewalls: https://medium.com/@bpolaszek/expose-a-rest-api-to-different-kinds-of-users-with-api-platform-part-1-4-713f3c6db86f